# Отглагольное прилагательное: её мысли путан(н)ы

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

По правилу в наречии *путано* нужно писать одну -*н*-, поскольку оно образовано от отглагольного прилагательного. В "Трёх товарищах" читаем: «*Через некоторое время он заговорил, сбивчиво и путанно*». По поводу краткого прилагательного *путаны* (например, мысли) та же Грамота даёт два разных ответа. Чем руководствоваться?

Comment: Я нашел только ответ Грамоты, похожий на ответ @Серж (нужно писать одну н). Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на другой ответ?

Comment: Нашел: "Ответы их весьма сбивчивы и путанны" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=264530)

Answer (score 2):

Прилагательное *путаный* и наречие *путано* пишутся с одной буквой Н, что указывается **в словарном приложении Правил 1956 года.** Прилагательное образовано от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида *путать.*

До этого встречались варианты письма: так,  в Нацкорпусе приведено 13 примеров с прилагательным  "путанный", но все они относятся к старым текстам.

«Три товарища» — роман Эриха Марии Ремарка, это 1932 год.

Согласно современным правилам надо писать: Через некоторое время он заговорил, сбивчиво и путано.

Comment: Нашла информацию, что "Три товарища" были переведены на русский язык только в 1959 году.

Comment: Значит, при переводе были нарушены правила орфографии, принятые в 1956 году, где по поводу  "путаный" нет никаких вариантов: и прилагательное, и наречие записаны в словаре-приложении с одной буквой Н.

Answer (score 0):

> Правильно: Ее мысли были пута**н**ы.
>
> Через некоторое время он заговорил, сбивчиво и пута**н**о.

По правилу, краткие формы прилагательных с качественным значением, полные формы которых передаются на письме **с одним н,** пишутся так же, как полные. Примеры: **делана, делано, деланы (от деланый 'неестественный, принуждённый'); путана, путано, путаны (от путаный 'нелогичный, сбивающий с толку'); учёна, учёно, учёны (от учёный 'основательно знающий что-либо'**). Так же пишутся формы сравнительной степени (деланее, путанее, учёнее) и наречия на -о (делано, путано).

> См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации : Полный академический справочник / под ред. В. В. Лопатина. – М. : Эксмо, 2006. – С. 105–107.

Comment: Ответ Грамоты: "Ответы их весьма сбивчивы и пута**нн**ы" (new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=264530). Ваши комментарии?

Comment: @MГ, скорее всего, при ответе на вопрос "Ответы их весьма сбивчивы и путанны" , они ориентировались § 101.

Comment: Краткие формы (кроме формы мужского рода) прилагательных с качественным значением, ***совпадающих по форме со страдательными причастиями прошедшего времени глаголов совершенного вида, пишутся с нн, напр.: воспитанна, воспитанно, воспитанны (от прилагательного воспитанный 'обнаруживающий результаты хорошего воспитания'); избалованна, избалованно, избалованны (от прилагательного избалованный 'привыкший к исполнению своих прихотей'); возвышенна, возвышенно, возвышенны (от прилагательного возвышенный 'полный высокого содержания').***

Comment: Такие прилагательные имеют формы сравнительной степени: воспитаннее, избалованнее, возвышеннее.

Answer (score 0):

1. Сегодня у нас **21 февраля 2024 года.**

И сейчас я решаю задачи преимущественно **по словарям** (орфографический и толковый), где все ответы есть. Лингвисты все уже **обозначили**, а пользователи должны **понять** это решение.

Русский орфографический словарь:
***путаный***, прил.

Большой толковый словарь.
**ПУТАНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое. 1. **Запутанный, беспорядочно переплетающийся**. П-ые нитки, волосы. П. след. П-ые тропы, улицы. 2. Такой, в котором трудно разобраться; **сбивчивый, нелогичный, неясный.** П-ая речь. П-ые слухи. П-ое письмо. П-ые мысли. 3. Нар.-разг. **Беспутный, легкомысленный; бестолковый**. П-ая твоя голова, душа (о человеке). Путано, нареч. (1-2 зн.). Заяц п. наследил. П. объяснять. Путаность, -и; ж. П. схемы, выступления.

2. Итак, ***путаный*** — это однозначно **прилагательное**, и при этом имеет **три** значения: **путаные** нитки, **путаная** речь и даже **путная/беспутная** голова. ***Путать*** — бесприставочный глагол несовершенного вида, и такое решение понятно. Прилагательное обозначает не конкретное действие (процессуальный признак, отнесенный ко времени), а  **качественный** признак как результат действия.